# KeyCloak 502 Gateway Error everytime the session is expired

Tags: nginx, session, cookies, keycloak

The session data is stored inside cookie. There are multiple ways the session can get expired which can be controlled from the interface, like Session Max, Session Idle. No matter the session timeout reason, after the session ends, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error blocking me out of every Keycloak page even the login page. Note that, deleting the cookie manually from browser restores normal behavior. [this is the error displayed] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXcTR.png)

I expect after the session expires, I am redirected to the authentication page where I am asked to give my credentials again. Here are the attached Keycloak settings that I am currently using to handle the sessions.
[Session settings: ] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir18j.png)
[Token settings: ] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YUvS.png)

Note that: I have intentionally kept the Session max timeout to be 2 minutes to recreate the bug after this interval

Here is the k8s command used to run keycloak:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  postgresql.conf: |2

    # postgresql config
    # - SSL -
    # ssl = off
    # ssl_cert_file = '/opt/bitnami/postgresql/certs/tls.crt'
    # ssl_key_file = '/opt/bitnami/postgresql/certs/tls.key'

    max_connections = 100
    shared_buffers = 128MB
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: keyclaok-2023070509560575-df
    companyId: 64623d28c01f7e3bf2919b6b
    databaseId: 64a53e355aecf20001998ee1
    deployedName: keyclaok-2023070509560575
    vpcId: 6462a2ab2eed1f0001aa7235
  name: keyclaok-2023070509560575-df
  namespace: keycloak
```